# How can you add jquery file based on existing files dynamically with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery1.js file that conflicts with another jquery2.js file intermittently. I would like to load the second jquery file only if the first is not present, because the modules that need these display intermittently throughout the site. So is it possible to search for at least the string or inner html in javascript and make a decision on that finding?

i.e. (in pseudocode)

```
if (jquery1 exists){do nothing}
else{document.write('<script>/jquery2.js</script>')}
```

or something along these lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a script loader like [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/) to manage this sort of dependancy?

```
yepnope({
    test: window.jQuery,
    nope: 'jquery2.js',
    complete: function () {
        // Initialise any dependant scripts
    }
});
```

Comment: This is very interesting. I am doing a lot of sites on Joomla and have been looking for a systematic solution that works consistently. This looks like it might make a good plugin for fixing these common CMS issues.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming jquery1.js has jQuery namespaced as `jQuery` (the default), you can do the following:

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/jquery2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Comment: This looks to be good, I will try these out in the morning to see what option works.

Answer (score 1):

I belive `$().jquery` will return the version you are using so you can try `if($().jquery === undefined)`